# (Django) DetailView template not displaying information

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Within my maintenance app, I have six models. I will include only 2 of the models that are relevant towards this question. There is a list of equipment (Listview) which displays properly. However, I'm having a problem creating a DetailView for each equipment. When I go to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/maintenance/equipments/1 it should display all equipment instance (details) relevant to equipment 1 but it displays back the equipment list page, i.e, http://127.0.0.1:8000/maintenance/equipments/.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Equipment(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing an Equipment (but not a specific type of equipment).
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    physicist = models.ForeignKey('Physicist', null=True, help_text= 'add information about the physicist')
    technician = models.ForeignKey('Technician', null=True, help_text= 'add information about the technician')
    # Physicist as a string rather than object because it hasn't been declared yet in the file.
    features = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the features of the equipment')
    machine_number = models.CharField('Number', max_length=30, null=True, help_text='Enter the Equipment number')
    specialty = models.ForeignKey(Specialty, null=True, help_text='Select a specialty for an equipment')
    # Specialty class has already been defined so we can specify the object above.
    assigned_technician = models.CharField(max_length=50, null= True, blank=True)
    #This is for the Technician who the repair of the Equipment is assigned to. 

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('equipment-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def display_specialty(self):

        return ', '.join([ specialty.name for specialty in self.specialty.all()[:3] ])
    display_specialty.short_description = 'Specialty'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

class EquipmentInstance(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text="Unique ID for this particular equipment across the entire database")
    equipment = models.ForeignKey('Equipment', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    delegate = models.ForeignKey('Physicist', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def is_overdue(self):
        if self.due_date and date.today() > self.due_date:
            return True
        return False

    MAINTENANCE_STATUS = (
        ('p', 'Past Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On Maintenance'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = MAINTENANCE_STATUS, blank=True, default='m', help_text='Equipment availability')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["due_date"]
        permissions = (("can_mark_maintained", "Set equipment as maintained"),) 

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object
        """
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.id,self.equipment.title)
```

**maintanance/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from qatrack.maintenance import views 
from qatrack.maintenance import models

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.MDashboard, name='m_dash'),
    url(r'^equipments/$', views.EquipmentListView.as_view(), name='equipments'),
    url(r'^equipment(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.EquipmentDetailView.as_view(), name='equipment-detail'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from qatrack.maintenance import models

class EquipmentListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'maintenance/equipment_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Equipment.objects.all()

    paginate_by = 10

class EquipmentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Equipment
    template_name = 'maintenance/equipment_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'equipment'
```

**equipment_list.html**

```
{% extends "maintenance/m_base.html" %}

{% block body %}

 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box">

          <h1>Equipment List</h1>

          {% if equipment_list %}
          <ul>
              {% for equipment in equipment_list %}
            <li>
              <a href="{{ equipment.get_absolute_url }}">{{ equipment.title }}</a> ({{equipment.physicist}}, {{equipment.technician}})
            </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          {% else %}
              <p>There are no equipments in the database.</p>

          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>

{% endblock body %}
```

**equipment_detail.html**

```
{% extends "maintenance/m_base.html" %}

{% block title %}Equipment Details{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <h1>Title: {{ equipment.title }}</h1>

  <h2>Machine Detail</h2>

  <p><strong>Physicist:</strong> <a href="">{{ equipment.physicist }}</a></p> <!-- physicist detail link not yet defined -->
  <p><strong>Technician:</strong> <a href="">{{ equipment.technician }}</a></p> <!-- technician detail link not yet defined -->
  <p><strong>Features:</strong> {{ equipment.features }}</p>
  <p><strong>Machine_number:</strong> {{ equipment.machine_number }}</p>  
  <p><strong>Specialty:</strong> {% for specialty in equipment.specialty.all %} {{ specialty }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}</p>  

    {% for type in equipment.equipmentinstance_set.all %}
    <hr>
    <p class="{% if type.status == 'a' %}text-success{% elif type.status == 'm' %}text-danger{% else %}text-warning{% endif %}">{{ type.get_status_display }}</p>
    {% if type.status != 'a' %}<p><strong>Due to be maintained:</strong> {{type.due_date}}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><strong>Imprint:</strong> {{type.imprint}}</p>
    <p class="text-muted"><strong>Id:</strong> {{type.id}}</p>
    {% endfor %}

  </div>

{% endblock body %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, RedirectView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static as static_url
from django.contrib import admin
from qatrack.maintenance.views import get_data
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"), name="home"),

    url(r'^accounts/', include('qatrack.accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^qa/', include('qatrack.qa.urls')),
    url(r'^servicelog/', include('qatrack.service_log.urls')),
    url(r'^parts/', include('qatrack.parts.urls')),
    url(r'^units/', include('qatrack.units.urls')),
    url(r'^issues/', include('qatrack.issue_tracker.urls')),
    url(r'^maintenance/', include('qatrack.maintenance.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have gone through a lot of questions similar to this here and applied them but I still can't get the DetailView to work. I will really appreciate any help. Thanks. After making changes I encountered this traceback error

> Internal Server Error: /maintenance/equipment1/ Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py",
>   line 77, in reverse
>       extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns] KeyError: 'equipments'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 41, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 217, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 215, in _get_response
>       response = response.render()   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py",
>   line 107, in render
>       self.content = self.rendered_content   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py",
>   line 84, in rendered_content
>       content = template.render(context, self._request)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py",
>   line 66, in render
>       return self.template.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 207, in render
>       return self._render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/utils.py",
>   line 107, in instrumented_test_render
>       return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 990, in render
>       bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 957, in render_annotated
>       return self.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
>   line 177, in render
>       return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/utils.py",
>   line 107, in instrumented_test_render
>       return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 990, in render
>       bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 957, in render_annotated
>       return self.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
>   line 177, in render
>       return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/utils.py",
>   line 107, in instrumented_test_render
>       return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 990, in render
>       bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 957, in render_annotated
>       return self.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
>   line 72, in render
>       result = block.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 990, in render
>       bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 957, in render_annotated
>       return self.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
>   line 322, in render
>       return nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 990, in render
>       bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 957, in render_annotated
>       return self.render(context)   File "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
>   line 458, in render
>       url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)   File
>   "/home/blesjoe1/venvs/qatrack3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py",
>   line 87, in reverse
>       raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'equipments' is not a
>   registered namespace [14/May/2018 16:05:33] "GET
>   /maintenance/equipment1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 215728

Comment: You say you tested `/maintenance/equipments/1` (with an `s`, without a trailing slash), but your URL pattern is for `/maintenance/equipment/1/` (without an s, with a trailing slash).

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, I corrected that. sorry for my silly mistake

Comment: You don't seem to have updated that part of the question, there is still a mismatch between the URL you are testing and the URL pattern.

Comment: I am trying to have a link from the listview page to the detailview page, and yes, there is a trailing slash which will be /maintenance/equipment/1/. I updated the urls but there is still no progress. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Your `url` is not correct

instead of

```
 url(r'^equipment(?:/(?P<pk>\d+))?/$', views.EquipmentDetailView.as_view(), name="equipment_detail"),
```

it should be:

```
url(r'^equipment/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.EquipmentDetailView.as_view(), name="equipment_detail"),
```

Comment: And also looks like there is a problem with `href` attribute value at the `equipment_list.html`: `{{ equipments.get_absolute_url }}` should be `{{ equipments.get_absolute_url }}`

Comment: Thanks, the 2 href attribute you have above look alike. Please, what do you mean?

Comment: @d2718nis meant that you have equipment with `s`, it should be without `s`, {{ equipment.get_absolute_url } in this templates `equipment_list.html`

Answer (score 1):

Update your `DetailView` with this:

```
class EquipmentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Equipment
    template_name = 'maintenance/equipment_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'equipment'
```

You don't need to override default method if you are not doing anything extra than the `DetailView` offers.

Comment: Thanks, this has been updated but the detailview html page still does not open up

Comment: Please update all the changes you made in your files. You url pattern has still problems mentioned in previous answer by another user. That might cause the problem. And add a traceback of error if there's any.

Comment: I updated the changes but there is a traceback of error

Comment: I see you still have a missing `/` in your url patterns:
`url(r'^equipment/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.EquipmentDetailView.as_view(), name='equipment-detail')`. You are still missing a `slash(/)` after `url(r'^equipment`

Comment: You have to access your page like this `localhost/maintenance/equipment/1`